# Input/output a vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector

Tl;dr I have a bunch of code and no way to know what's wrong and how to fix it.

This program needs to have a class "Item" store the name, price, etc. A second class has to make a list of items and have the option of printing, deleting items, etc. I haven't learned std::list yet so I'm using vectors.  The only error I get is "expected primary-expression before 'groceries'" in the second to last line.

```
    class Item
    {
      protected: 
        string itemName, unit;     // (i.e. can, box, pounds, or ounces)
        double numberToBuy, unitPrice, extendedPrice;

      public:    
        Item();
        Item (string, string, double, double);
        string getName ();
        string getUnit();
        double getNumberToBuy();
        double getUnitPrice();
        double getExtendedPrice();
        void printItem();
    };

    class List
    {
      private: 
        Item item;
        int numberOfItems;
        vector <Item> groceries;

      public:     
        void addItem();
        void print();
    };

    void List::addItem()
    {  
      int stop;

      while (stop != 666) 
      { 
        cout << "Enter the name of your item "  << endl;
        string name;
        getline(cin, name);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Enter the units of your item "  << endl;
        string unit;
        getline(cin, unit);
        cout << "Enter the amount you would like to buy "<< endl;
        double amount;
        cin >> amount;
        cout << "Enter the price of your item " <<  endl;
        double price;
        cin >> price;
        //Item *item = new Item(name, unit, amount, price); 
        // ^^^I don't think I need this but I'm not quite sure.
        groceries.push_back(item);
        cin >> stop;
      }
    }

    void List::print()
    {
      auto v = vector<Item> groceries; 

      copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<Item>(cout, " "));
    }
```

Comment: In `addItem` you need a way to get the information you gathered (`name` , `amount` , etc) into a new item first, before you push it into the vector. Printing would involve calling the `printItem` function for each object in the vector, not simly copying raw data to cout.

Comment: Would creating set methods for class Item and then calling them from within `addItem` work? I kind of see what you're saying about `printItem` but I'm not sure how to access each object in the vector. Could I use a loop?  @user1320881

Comment: Actually, I figured the second part out. Thank you for nudging me in the right direction, @user1320881

Answer (score 1):

In your Item class, you need to define **set** type functions so that the string and double member data can acquire values. As of now, you only have **get** type functions defined that return values.

For example...

```
void setNumberToBuy(const double& val) {
    numberToBuy = val;
}
```

Then, inside your List::addItem() member function you need to call those **set** type functions in order to supply the item object with data...

```
cout << "Enter the amount you would like to buy " << endl;
double amount;
cin >> amount;
item.setNumberToBuy(amount);
```

... so that at the end, when you do this...

```
groceries.push_back(item);
```

... the item object will be full of data.

Comment: Do all his homework and fix List::print aswell while you're at it :)

Comment: He saved you from having to type "yes" to my follow up question @user1320881

Comment: Thanks, @dspfnder. That was a dumb oversight on my part. How come it's a `const double &val` (as opposed to just double val)?

Comment: @user5394631, you can do 'double val'. double is a small data type so in this case it would be okay to pass by value and when you pass by value const is pointless because a copy will be made and the caller's object will not be modified. I just have a habit of doing 'const type& label'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete implementation...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Item
{
private:
    string itemName{ "" }, unit{""};     // (i.e. can, box, pounds, or ounces)
    double numberToBuy{ 0.0 }, unitPrice{ 0.0 }, extendedPrice{ 0.0 };

public:
    Item() {}
    Item(string iN, string u, double nTB, double uP, double eP):
        itemName{ iN }, unit{ u }, numberToBuy{ nTB }, unitPrice{ uP }, extendedPrice{ eP } {
    }
    ~Item() {}

    // set functions
    void setName(const string& iN) {
        itemName = iN;
    }
    void setUnit(const string& u) {
        unit = u;
    }
    void setNumberToBuy(double nTB) {
        numberToBuy = nTB;
    }
    void setUnitPrice(double uP) {
        unitPrice = uP;
    }
    void setExtendedPrice(double eP) {
        extendedPrice = eP;
    }

    string getName();
    string getUnit();
    double getNumberToBuy();
    double getUnitPrice();
    double getExtendedPrice();
    void printItem();

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&^, const Item&);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Item& item) {
    os << itemName << " " << unit << " " << numberToBuy << " " << unitPrice << " " << extendedPrice << endl;
    return os;
}

class List
{
private:
    Item item;
    int numberOfItems;
    vector <Item> groceries;

public:
    void addItem();
    void print();
};

void List::addItem()
{
    int stop;
    double num{0.0};
    string str{""};

    while (stop != 666)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name of your item " << endl;     
        getline(cin, str);
        cin.ignore();
        item.setName(str);
        cout << "Enter the units of your item " << endl;        
        getline(cin, str);
        item.setUnit(str);
        cout << "Enter the amount you would like to buy " << endl;      
        cin >> num;
        item.setNumberToBuy(num);
        cout << "Enter the price of your item " << endl;        
        cin >> num;
        item.setUnitPrice(num);
        cout << "Set the extended price " << endl;
        cin >> num;
        item.setExtendedPrice(num);
        groceries.push_back(item); // now it's full of data
        cin >> stop;
    }
}
void List::print()
{
    auto v = vector<Item> groceries;

    copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<Item>(cout, " "));
}
```

Note the friend ostream& operator<< function added in Item to make the List::print function work.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much, @dspfnder